# How do I make a slideshow out of images that are pulled from a database?

Tags: php, css

Me and my friends have a PHP project that we're working on together, our teacher gave us a PHP project with a bunch of PHP files and we're supposed to fix some of the problems within them and also add some new stuff.

I'm trying to make a slideshow out of images pulled out of a database using PHP, but all the slideshow tutorials I've seen require CSS or java script (that I have no clue about), but I can't use the ids or classes within the php code.

This is the code our teacher wrote, so that it pulls out the images from the database.

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="'.$row['url'].'" data-lightbox="gallery" 
               data-title="'.$row['title'].'">
                   <img src="'.$row['url'].'" 
                    alt="'.$row['title'].'" width="300px" />
              </a>';
?>
```

[it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8UZX.png)

And this is the CSS code I'm trying to use, so it would make a slideshow out of the images:

@keyframes slider {

```
        0% {
            left: 0;
        }
        20% {
            left: 0;
        }
        25% {
            left: -100%;
        }
        45% {
            left: -100%;
        }
        50% {
            left: -200%;
        }
        70% {
            left: -200%;
        }
        75 {
            left: -300%;
        }
        95% {
            left: -300%;
        }
        100% {
        left: -400%;
        }
    }

    #slider {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #slider figure img {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }

    #slider figure {
        position: relative;
        width: 500%;
        margin: 0;
        left: 0;
        tet-align: left;
        font-size: 0;
        animation: 20s slider infinite;
    }
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could help us out here. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: i don't get your problem "I can't use CSS for the PHP code."? can you show me what result you want

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear, I ment that I can't use the ids or classes within the php code. I'm not that great with php unfortunately.

Comment: you php to print what class you need is correct, i don't see any problem

Comment: but when I tried using the ids within the php code, it won't show me the slideshow. Like I've tried using '<div id="slider">';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {...

Comment: You need to use echo before the div in your example.

Comment: That was something that I forgot, after that it still wouldn't work and then I remembered that I forgot to add <figure> which is something I need for the slideshow. I managed to solve it now, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, was that I forgot to add the html tag (figure) which is something that I needed for the slideshow. I managed to solve it now.